# Append to next row each time function called

Tags: python, pandas

The function `Capture(filename)` reads the output `filename.txt` and dumps out the necessary stuff into a `Data.csv` file. But each time I call the Capture function, the data that gets dumped is rewritten in the same row.

```
def Capture(filename):
    impedance = 0 
    losses = {} 
    frequencies = {} 
    Xtalk = {}
    rows = []
    with open(PostProcessingFolder + '\Output_' + filename +'_LOG.txt') as f:
        for l in f:
            if l.startswith('Impedance = '):
                v = l[12:-7] 
                impedance = float(v)
            if l.startswith('Xtalk'):
                m = f.next()
                n = f.next()
                a = m.find('Step response Next')
                b = m.find('mV', a)
                frequencies[l + "Step response Next"] = str(m[a+20:b].strip())                    
                c = n.find('Step response Fext peak')
                d = n.find('@', c)
                e = n.find('inches', d)
                g = n.find('mV', e)
                frequencies[l + "Step response Fext peak @" + str(n[d+1:e].strip()) + "inches"] = str(n[e+7:g].strip())
            if l.startswith('Loss per inch'): 
                start = l.find('@') 
                stop1 = l.find('GHz', start) 
                stop2 = l.find('dB', start)
                frequencies['filename'] = filename
                frequencies['impedance (Ohms)'] = impedance
                frequencies["Loss per inch @" + str(float(l[start+1:stop1].strip())) + "GHz"] = float(l[stop1+5:stop2].strip())
    rows.append(frequencies)
    print(rows)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    #df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('Data.csv')
```

Is there a way i can add the data to the next consecutive row each time this function is called?

Comment: Haven't really worked with this but couldn't you make a global variable to hold the row number? Or perhaps use a second argument for the function to represent the row you want to write to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the declaration of the list `row`. Every time you are calling the method it creates an empty list. Declare your list outside the method and it should work fine. I would suggest using OOPS based approach.

```
class Text:
    def __init__:
        self.rows= list()
   def capture(self):
        //put your code. user rows as self.rows.append()

if __name__ = "__main__":
    tob = Text()
    tob.capture() // or you can call it in your own way.
    //here your values of rows will persist until you rerun this program.
```

Comment: Yes this really helped. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Ok, if this helped then the question was not completely clear.... but the rows.append(frequencies) statement still needs to be indented with another 4

Comment: @user2413548: not exactly, if you see `frequencies` is having different `keys` for every iteration. However, if there comes the same key then data will be overwritten. So, in that scenario I agree `append` should be intended, but if the user is sure that there won't be duplicate lines, then there shouldn't be any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need more indents on your `rows.append` line:

While you have

```
rows = []
with open(PostProcessingFolder + '\Output_' + filename +'_LOG.txt') as f:
        for l in f:
            ...
rows.append(frequencies)
```

You need:

```
rows = []
with open(PostProcessingFolder + '\Output_' + filename +'_LOG.txt') as f:
        for l in f:
            ...
            rows.append(frequencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a bit more grip, separate some functionality:

```
def Capture(filename):
    impedance = 0
    # losses = {} 
    # frequencies = {} 
    Xtalk = {}
    with open(PostProcessingFolder + '\Output_' + filename +'_LOG.txt') as f:
        for l in f:
            if l.startswith('Impedance = '):
                v = l[12:-7]
                impedance = float(v)
            if l.startswith('Xtalk'):
                m = f.next()
                n = f.next()
                a = m.find('Step response Next')
                b = m.find('mV', a)
                frequencies[l + "Step response Next"] = str(m[a+20:b].strip())                
                c = n.find('Step response Fext peak')
                d = n.find('@', c)
                e = n.find('inches', d)
                g = n.find('mV', e)
                frequencies[l + "Step response Fext peak @" + str(n[d+1:e].strip()) + "inches"] = str(n[e+7:g].strip())
            if l.startswith('Loss per inch'):
                start = l.find('@')
                stop1 = l.find('GHz', start)
                stop2 = l.find('dB', start)
                frequencies['filename'] = filename
                frequencies['impedance (Ohms)'] = impedance
                frequencies["Loss per inch @" + str(float(l[start+1:stop1].strip())) + "GHz"] = float(l[stop1+5:stop2].strip())
        yield frequencies

# just the rows
# print([r for r in Capture(filename)])

# build the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([r for r in Capture(filename)])
df.to_csv('Data.csv')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the dataframe part be inside the function?

Comment: No, Capture() generates the records, this way you init the dataframe using Capture(). But you can use Capture() now also for other purpose. You can easily try it, since you have the input data